# Android Studio Emulator Cannot connect to Internet behind Proxy Server in Linux

Tags: android, linux, proxy, android-emulator

I'm having trouble connecting Android studio emulator to Internet behind proxy.

I have enabled permission in android Manifest.xml

```html
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And the app works perfectly well in USB Debug mode.
This is the error i get when i run the app on Emulator. 
Following is my Logcat .

```html
D/makeGitHubSearchQuery: Inside Function
D/makeGitHubSearchQuery: HTTP
D/makeGitHubSearchQuery: https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=HTTP&sort=stars
D/OnOptionsItemSelected: action_search
W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "api.github.com": No address associated with hostname
W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:470)
W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:384)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:231)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
W/System.err:     at com.example.android.datafrominternet.utilities.NetworkUtils.getResponseFromHttpUrl(NetworkUtils.java:76)
W/System.err:     at com.example.android.datafrominternet.MainActivity$GithubQueryTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:77)
W/System.err:     at com.example.android.datafrominternet.MainActivity$GithubQueryTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:71)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451)
```

Please guide me in setting the Proxy settings in Android emulator.

Comment: have you set up proxy on the emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command to open emulator with the desired proxy.

```
emulator -avd [emulator_name] -http-proxy [proxy ip address]:[port]
```

[official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#proxy)