# Android Studio Emulator no internet with proxy

Tags: android-studio, proxy

I recently installed Android Studio 2.3.1 on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.
When I run an emulator that I create using android AVD the emulator does not have internet connection (in general, not even in chrome).

My computer is behind a proxy server. I set the proxy through the ubuntu settings, as well as manually through /etc/environment and it works, I am writing this post on the mentioned computer.
I tried to set the proxy from within the emulator in the android settings but it didn't help.

I tried to follow the instructions in the following link but couldn't find the "Hardware section" or any place that mentions GSM modem support in the AVD:
[No internet access in Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682257/no-internet-access-in-android-emulator)

I also found a lot saying to run the emulator from terminal with a proxy flag, as seen here: [Android Studio Emulator Cannot connect to Internet behind Proxy Server in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42220388/android-studio-emulator-cannot-connect-to-internet-behind-proxy-server-in-linux)
but my terminal doesn't recognize the commands. When I type in (in either the terminal within Android Studio or an external terminal) an "emulator command" or "android list avd" (as I found elsewhere) I get "No command 'android' found" or "emulator: command not found". The bin installation directory of Android Studio is included in my PATH variable. What am I doing wrong?

This is my first time installing Android Studio, I followed the instructions from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start and the links it provides, but maybe I did some things wrong?

I know this questioned has been asked many times before, but I could not find a solution that I could get to work, and all relevant google links have become purple from all my searches. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Please tell me if any other details need to be provided.

Comment: Did you make it work?

Comment: sorry, unfortunately i didn't. I ended up doing  a different non-android related project (not just because of this, but stuff happened).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout proxy settings in,

1. File > Settings > System settings > HTTP Proxy
2. Project gradle.properties
3. ~/.gradle/gradle.properties

Let us know if it worked.

Comment: I am sorry, I haven't been dealing with this for some time now, and I am doing other things that are completely unrelated. will not have a chance to check this. Thanks for the response in any case